# Change background color of head navigation elements (and shaded)

Tags: beamer, color, backgrounds, highlighting, navigation

I want to change the background (as a rectangle around, similar to the footer) in the two head navigation bars, for section and subsection. So that the currently active elements have one color, e.g. white, and the shaded elements have a different color, e.g. green.

Here is the mwe:

```latex
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\usetheme{Singapore}
\usecolortheme{spruce}

\title{MWE}
\author{trylks}
\date{\today}
\newcommand{\easection}[4]{\section{#1}

\subsection{What}\begin{frame}#2\end{frame}
\subsection{Why}\begin{frame}#3\end{frame}
\subsection{Who}\begin{frame}#4\end{frame}}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
\insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{}
\insertsubsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{}
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}
\easection{A}{a}{b}{c}
\easection{B}{d}{e}{f}
\easection{C}{g}{h}{i}
\easection{E}{j}{k}{l}
\easection{D}{m}{n}{o}
\frame{\titlepage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68321/134144

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the navigation bars into `beamercolorbox`es:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\usetheme{Singapore}
\usecolortheme{spruce}

\title{MWE}
\author{trylks}
\date{\today}
\newcommand{\easection}[4]{\section{#1}

\subsection{What}\begin{frame}#2\end{frame}
\subsection{Why}\begin{frame}#3\end{frame}
\subsection{Who}\begin{frame}#4\end{frame}}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=white!50!MSUgreen,fg=white}
}


\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{section in head/foot}%
    \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{subsection in head/foot}%
    \insertsubsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}
\easection{A}{a}{b}{c}
\easection{B}{d}{e}{f}
\easection{C}{g}{h}{i}
\easection{E}{j}{k}{l}
\easection{D}{m}{n}{o}
\frame{\titlepage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. How can I use `beamercolorbox` to have a different background color in the active section with respect to other sections?